# Error in emulator view but android studio view is correct

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have been trying to create a 4 image view grid in my android studio by constraint layout, on screen it is looking nice but in emulator 2 first column of images is correct but second column of images is smaller in size.
please somebody help me to solve this issue.  I am totally new in android programming. doing what my best is

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/devslopesbanner" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/devslopesprofilelogo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:text="DevSloves"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logoo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.71"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/camerabutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView11"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/favoritebutton" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/favoritebutton" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="480dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView17"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,9:16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView19"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/imagesimage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView19"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,9:16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logoo"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/codeimage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,9:16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView18"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/videosimage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView18"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,9:16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.372"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView19"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dataimage" />
```

Comment: Are you trying to create 2x2 grid layout? please provide a design of your requirement

Comment: I am sorry, can't provide the design, Stack isn't allowing me now to provide photo.

Comment: suggest something helpful

Comment: just share a rough layout how you want the layout to be like. You can attach image link to the question

Comment: i need 10 reputation point to post share an image. currently i don' t have it